# Execute a windows application (with GUI) remotely (no RDP)

Tags: windows, remote, gui, remote-execution

I've my thunderbird email client in my personal workstation. What I would like to do is execute this exact client from my laptop. Having access to the same exact GUI but from my laptop. Hence, all the emails, files, etc that change, will be changed in the workstation.

I'm not looking for a remote desktop or similar. I want to just being able to execute the thunderbird client and having access to ONLY the GUI of the thunderbird client in my laptop, not the entire system.

Is there any way? I saw something about psExec but as far as I know is for command line application/processes.

Comment: Why not install Thunderbird on the laptop ?

Comment: Good point indeed. I've centralized all the email in this thunderbird in the workstation. If for example I've been working all day replying, moving or archiving emails and then I move to the laptop since It is a local instance, all the work is "gone" (not done in fact). For this reason I would like to always use always the same "instance" independently of the computer.

Comment: The only technology I know that does it is RemoteApp, which is only available for Windows Server.

Comment: If the mailserver has plenty of space, reconfigure it as IMAP rather than POP and set it up on both computers. Your changes will then sync between the computers. Note that after you set it up as IMAP, you will have to get the email from the main computer back into the mail server, otherwise you only have the last emails.

Comment: Easily do-able with X11 on Linux /Unix -- but your question is tagged `windows`. That means you'll need to setup WSL on Windows, switch to the LInux Thunderbird, and then you'll be able to run and pop up that Thunderbird window on any computer running an X Server..

Comment: Mailserver in this case have not plenty of space, but the problem is that I've several email addresses, some of them working with IMAP and others with POP. For this reason I need an "unifying" solution that is not relying on this and that stores everything in local.

Answer (score 0):

I've found this, and solves perfectly what I was looking for (indeed thanks harrymc for the idea):

https://github.com/kimmknight/remoteapptool

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).